# Animate text position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a custom progress bar. I have text I want to move with a progress when animated. But instead text disappears and reappears in new position (see gif below).

code:

```
private struct MyProgressBar: View {
    let progress: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .frame(height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    let progressWidth = geo.size.width * progress
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: progressWidth)
                        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                            bubble(progress)
                                .fixedSize()
                                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.trailing) { d in
                                    d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                                }
                                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.top) { d in
                                    d[.bottom]
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
        .padding()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func bubble(_ progress: Double) -> some View {
        Text(progress.formatted(.percent))
            .monospacedDigit()
            .padding(5.0)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }

    }
}

struct MyProgressBarExample: View {
    @State private var progress: Double = 0.3
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyProgressBar(progress: progress)
            VStack {
                Button("change") {
                    withAnimation() {
                        progress = Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
                    }
                }
                Slider(
                    value: $progress.animation(),
                    in: 0.0...1.0,
                    step: 0.005
                )
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a dynamic value text disappears and reappears but if I change the text to some constant string like "hello" then it moves fine.

[image: situation]
[image: moves fine with constant string]

How to make text with green background move instead of appearing and disappearing?

Comment: I don't know for certain but I wonder what would happen if you made the bubble not a `Text` but a view that had the `Text` in it? That way, the view (with the green background) will always be consistent and would never not be there. But the text inside it would animate? Maybe.

Comment: Also... the animations in the gifs are very quick to easily spot the difference between them. At that speed it's a very subtle difference. 

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but the Text behaves the same (disappears/reappears).

Comment: I replaced gifs (enabled slow animations in simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.drawingGroup` to your bubble. Don't think it needs to be a `ViewBuilder` either:

```swift
    private func bubble(_ progress: Double) -> some View {
        Text(progress.formatted(.percent))
            .monospacedDigit()
            .padding(5.0)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            .drawingGroup() // <-- HERE
    }
```

Comment: It works! thanks :) Tested on Xcode 14.2, simulator with iOS 16.2.

Comment: I just found out that ".contentTransition(.identity)" also works somehow